# Оформление пакета для NPM

Tags: npm, node.js

Здравствуйте.
Решил я тут создать и опубликовать пакет для node.js. Прочитал пару статей по оформлению пакетов, дал команду "npm init" и понеслась.
Написал код, написал README.md, сохранил всё на gitlab, сделал "npm publish" и.. не впечатлило.

Как так у всех получается содержимое README.md "прицеплять" как документацию на странице пакета (например: https ://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session), а у меня получилось нечто такое: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sticky-cluster

Содержимое package.json:

```
{
    "author": {
    "name": "Valeriy V. Pushkar",
    "email": ""
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https ://github.com/kainpl/express-sticky-cluster/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "http-proxy": "*",
    "merge": "*",
    "cookie": "*"
  },
  "description": "Sticky session balancer based on a cluster and node-http-proxy modules, with express and socket.io support",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "directories": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "671d155887bf4b6b3055989ef65b077c022df890",
    "tarball": "https ://registry.npmjs.org/express-sticky-cluster/-/express-sticky-cluster-0.0.1.tgz"
  },
  "gitHead": "066bc4d03d2d058ff534be1949120a41d0507464",
  "homepage": "https ://github.com/kainpl/express-sticky-cluster#readme",
  "keywords": [
    "express.js",
    "cluster",
    "http-proxy",
    "socket.io",
    "sticky-cluster",
    "sticky-sessions"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "kain_pl",
      "email": ""
    }
  ],
  "name": "express-sticky-cluster",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "https ://github.com/kainpl/express-sticky-cluster#readme",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https ://github.com/kainpl/express-sticky-cluster.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "version": "0.1.1"
}
```

Comment: Извините за содержимое, не разобрался как тут "код" оформлять.

Comment: Уберите поле readme. Тогда npm сам всё сделает

Comment: Alexey Ten, Спасибо! Всё отлично!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо! Ответ на вопрос:

Уберите поле readme. Тогда npm сам всё сделает – [Alexey Ten](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190728/alexey-ten)